# How to run a python code in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

It's the first time I am using colab notebook. I write the code and when I try to execute it using ctrl+ enter key it runs but doesn't display output.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides Jupyter Notebook like interface to run Python code on online Virtual Machines. In this article, we will see how to run simple Python code on Google Colab.

Step #1: Open [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

Step #2: Select New Python3 Notebook

Step #3: Start Typing code into the code cells.

Step #4: To add new cell, click on Insert->Code Cell

Step #5: To run a particular cell, select the cell and press Ctlr + ENTER keys.

Output after successful run